# Android Layout Priority?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I studied Android XML but I got a problem about layouts.
As you can see, I declared 2 linear layouts and 1 relative layout, so the order is Linear (1) - Relative (2) - Linear (3)
However when I run this, the display shows Linear (1) - Linear (3) - Relative (2).

So, I wonder if there is a priority or rules in Layouts :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff0000"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Linear_Layout1 (1)" 
        />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        >   
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Relative_layout1 (2)"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
            android:textSize="19dp" 
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mosquito"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="#ffff0000"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text01"
            />
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff0f0f0"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text03"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Linear_layout2 (3)"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's happening maybe because the `RelativeLayout` has height `match_parent`, change it to `wrap_content` and check. And your `LinearLayout(2)` is inside `RelativeLayout`. Try putting it outside.

Comment: define below property for 3rd `LinearLayout` which is in `RelativeLayout`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No There isn't any priority.

You have set **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** to **text01** & there isn't any alignment to any child view of relative layout.

When you are not assigning any alignment to child view of relative layout than there are overlapped.(and added to stack from bottom to top)

Check out updated view which add views in relative layout from top to bottom

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/backBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Linear_Layout1 (1)" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Relative_layout1 (2)"
        android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
        android:textSize="19dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text01"
        android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:text="Mosquito"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text02"
        android:background="#fff0f0f0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Linear_layout2 (3)" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff0000">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Linear_Layout1 (1)"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff000000">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Relative_layout1 (2)"
            android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mosquito"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:background="#ffff0000"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text01"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff0f0f0">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text03"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Linear_layout2 (3)"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```